# manipulate icon-position of samba-shares on caja-desktop

Tags: caja

I know how to manipulate the position of desktop icons with the `gio set` command

`gio set -t string '/home/user/Schreibtisch/example' 'metadata::cajas-icon-position' '500,500'`

But this does not works with samba-shares. I also can't find the samba-shares in `~.local/share/gvfs-metadata/` (where are external drives)

How dows one manipulate the Icons of samba-shares on Caja Desktops with gio?

Answer (score 0):

The drives, shares, and folder positions are saved in a text file here:

~/.config/caja/desktop-metadata

Icon positions in this text file can be changed with a text editor.  After running caja -q, or pkill caja, the icons will appear at the new location.

I wrote a bash script that will save and load icon positions (including the folder icons). Usage is

```
./icons.sh save [name]
./icons.sh load [name]
```

The name argument is optional, in case you want to save different configurations. You may have to adjust the lines under #config info to accommodate your OS.

```
#!/bin/bash

#config info
desktop=~/Desktop/*
metastr="metadata::caja-icon-position"
metafile=~/.config/caja/desktop-metadata
saveicon=~/.icon.txt
savemeta=~/.iconmeta.txt
file_manager=caja

saveinfo(){
cat /dev/null > "$saveicon"
for f in $desktop;do
p=$(gio info -a "$metastr" "$f"|grep "$metastr"|awk '{print $2}')
echo "$f;$p">>"$saveicon"
done
#save metafile
cp "$metafile" "$savemeta"
zenity --notification --window-icon="/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/categories/applications-other.png" --text "Icon Positions Saved"
}

loadinfo(){
str=$(cat "$saveicon")
if [ -z "$str" ];then
echo "$saveicon not found"
exit
fi

for fl in $str;do
f=$(echo "$fl"|cut -d';' -f1)
p=$(echo "$fl"|cut -d';' -f2)
gio set -t string "$f" "$metastr" "$p"
done
#load metafile
cp "$savemeta" "$metafile"
#restart file manager
pkill "$file_manager"
}

if [ -z "$1" ];then
echo "Saves or loads icon positions"
echo " Usage:"
echo "$0 save [name]"
echo "$0 load [name]"
exit
fi

if [ -n "$2" ];then
  saveicon="$2"
  savemeta="$2_meta"
fi

if [ "$1" = "save" ];then
saveinfo
fi

if [ "$1" = "load" ];then
loadinfo
fi
```